# Rails Eager loading explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have simplified my project to this so i can understand the better the eager loading part of RoR 3.2.13 . These are my classes:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :posts
end
```

And

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :person_id
  belongs_to :person
end
```

When i do something like

```
people_data = Person.includes(:posts)
```

IRB shows the following SQL:

```
Person Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` 
Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`person_id` IN (1, 2)
```

And the resulting object its like:

```
=> [#<Person id: 1, name: "Ernie">, #<Person id: 2, name: "Bert">]
```

Notice that there are only 2 person objects, no posts. How can i get a simple data structure with person AND its posts. I want to do this in a single instruction, i dont want to do a foreach in the people array.

Im expecting something like this:

```
[#<Person id: 1, name: "Ernie">, [#<Array 0 => #<Post id:1, name: "Hi">, 1 => #<Post id:2, name: "Hello"> > ....
```

Comment: what it given `Person.first.posts` with `include` in your model?

Comment: @Rajarshi Das. Sure, but i need the entire array with the posts in each position of the array included in the person object. I need the entire list, not just one item of the list. :(

Comment: Eager loading IS working. It's retrieving all the posts eagerly (in one query), isn't it?

Comment: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Comment: @Mischa, no it isn't. The result object is an array with 2 Person objects. No Post objects at all :(

Comment: The point is that when you try `Person.first.posts` that it doesn't perform a query for each post. Not that it constructs an array with all persons and all posts.

Comment: `Person.eager_load(:posts).to_a` try this

Comment: Thanks for advice @RajarshiDas. It did not work. It performed both SQLs perfectly, but returning object still being the 2 Person objects.

Comment: @crackedmind Thanks, tried all of them with same results.

Comment: Is it about eager loading or about getting all the objects in one array? Those two things are not the same!

Comment: you mistake what eager loading is supposed to do.

Comment: @sevenseacat in order to learn, would you be more specific please and expose your arguments?

Comment: it loads the posts so if you call something like `people_data.map(&:posts)`, it won't make a separate trip back to the database for each person's posts, because they're all already (eagerly) loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your results to receive expected array

```
Person.includes(:posts).all.map{|person| [person, person.posts]}
```

Comment: Excelent this did it. How can i perform this cleaner, or without the map?

Comment: @DavidMauricio, this does indeed construct the wanted array, but is it really what you need? Why do you need that array with all the persons and posts. As I am trying to explain: eager loading *is* working. Just use it the way it was supposed to be used.

Comment: Indeed, it is working, how can i send that structure to another context and go through the posts, for each person? Thats a different question, but it surely needs the eager loading inside one structure in outer scope.

Comment: @DavidMauricio what do you mean by another context? A view? If you set an instance variable and use that in a view the posts are still eagerly loaded.

Comment: @Mischa, for instance, another application. I just realized i can use (as you said) .as_json(:includes => :posts) and will work.

Comment: Yes, JSON is probably the best solution then.

Answer (score 3):

[Eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) **is working**. It's retrieving all the posts eagerly (in one query). Eager loading **does not** construct an array with all posts and persons.

```
# With eager loading
people_data = Person.includes(:posts) # 2 queries: 1 for persons, 1 for posts
people_data.first.posts.each do |post|
  # No queries
end

# Without eager loading
people_data = Person.all # 1 query for persons
people_data.first.posts.each do |post|
  # Query for each post
end
```

Note that in both cases `people_data` will contain (a similar looking) `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. (It's not an array!) You will only see the benefit of the eager loading when you start using the associated records.

Unless you have a special reason for wanting to build an array with all persons and posts, you should use eager loading like it was meant to be used. This is more efficient than trying to build your own array.

Comment: I tried eager_load but got same results, i did it like this: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html with no luck

Comment: @DavidMauricio just try the code in my answer and you'll see that you *don't have to* construct an array with all persons and posts. Rails handles the eager loading for you in the background. You don't need `eager_load` either, `includes` is enough.

Comment: @Mischa yeah i see it, it wont perform another query. How can i return the people data through JSON request and perform a for each post in each person?

Comment: @DavidMauricio you can use `as_json` like this: `people_data.as_json(:include => :posts)`. You may want to look into [JBuilder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder) or [RABL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl).

Answer (score 1):

The result of your query eager loads the posts as the result of the `Person#posts` method. I'm not quite clear on the format of the output you are expecting. If you simply want two arrays, one of people and one of all posts by those people you can split it into two queries.

```
@people = Person.where(...)
@posts = Post.where(person_id: @people)
```

This is the same query done by eager loading, but it will return posts in their own array.

Comment: Interesting, i didnt know that. I really want both of the results of your code in the same structure. Thanks